# Return the a grouped collection with the original entity not anonym type

Tags: c#, linq

How can I return the groupedMembers where each member is of type Member  with all its existing values and the changed Name property without using an anonym type?

I do not want to use the .Select() method to copy/paste all original Member values in the anonym type...

```
var groupedMembers = from r in dataRows 
                    join m in members on r.Name equals m.Name
                    group r by r.Name into g
                    select new { Name = String.Format("{0} ({1})", g.Key, g.Count()) };



var dataRows = new List<GenericDataRow> { 
    new GenericDataRow { Name = "E1" },
    new GenericDataRow { Name = "E1" }, 
    new GenericDataRow { Name = "E1" }, 
    new GenericDataRow { Name = "E1" }, 
    new GenericDataRow { Name = "E2" },
    new GenericDataRow { Name = "E2" }, 
    new GenericDataRow { Name = "E2" } 
};          

var members = new List<OtlClientMember> { 
    new Member { Name = "E1" },
    new Member { Name = "E2" },
    new Member { Name = "E3" },
    new Member { Name = "E4" },                         
};
```

**Output**

```
E1 (4)
E2 (3)
```

Comment: Can you model what your desired output looks like please? It's hard to discern exactly what you are looking for from your post. Thanks.

Comment: Are you OK with overwriting the existing object's name, or do you want to create a copy of the object with a new name?

Comment: Overwrite the existing Name property is a must. I would like to return the original Member object with all former values if thats possible...

Answer (score 0):

If `Name` is what makes `GenericDataRow` unique then you need to implement the `IEquatable<GenericDataRow>` as well as overriding `GetHashCode` and `Equals(object)`. Example below.

```
    private class GenericDataRow : IEquatable<GenericDataRow>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool Equals(GenericDataRow other)
        {
            return Name.Equals(other.Name);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Name.GetHashCode();
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return Equals(obj as GenericDataRow);
        }
    }
```

With the following Linq:

```
var groupedMembers = from r in dataRows 
                join m in members on r.Name equals m.Name
                group r by r into g
                select new { Name = String.Format("{0} ({1})", g.Key.Name, g.Count()) };
```

Comment: Thats not what I asked for Rob. Of course my business object has the Equals overriden but thats another topic.

Comment: I'll bow out then because I clearly don't understand what you are looking for. Apologies.

Comment: I do not want to make select new { xxx } and return anonymous type I want to return the original Member class objects with the new Name property.

Comment: I thought that's what my solution gave you. In my solution, the Key property was a full GenericDataRow object.

Comment: Ok Rob, but how would your linq query look like?

Comment: I executed your new query and still it returns not the whole member object.

Comment: That's because I'm specifically returning `g.Key.Name` to match your original query. In this case `g.Key` is the whole `GenericDataRow` object. Do with it as you wish.

Comment: Yes but I need to return the GenericDataRow which is put as r into 'g' and for me it seems not possible to return the original type Member so I can return the query outside of a method. With the anonym result its not possible and I do not want to make select new Member{ Name = g.Name } and copy/paste all maybe 100 values thats very cumbersome. Sorry for your time you invested but for me its not a helpfull solution.